# How do I get a level 3 locator map?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have tried just about everything I can think of and my maps are always 0/4 or 1/4 I need a 3/4 or 4/4 map that's larger. The only way I have gotten them is to spawn in with them and have a starting map thing I need it for an older map and I cant change the world settings like bonus chest and starting map.

How do I get a level 3 locator map?

Comment: I know that MCPE is weird, but what the heck is a "level 3 locator map"?

Comment: @Fabian a map with a pointer and zoom of 3. They are craftable

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to surround an existing locator map with paper at a crafting table. Or simply, 8 paper and a locator map.

EDIT:

To make a locator map:

[image: to make a map]

To zoom it out:

[image: to zoom out]

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your map to level 4 to see your X and Y location, but you can see your player indicators (little arrow looking thingies) with level 3. Also, to get more visibility on it, just walk around with it out.

Answer (score 0):

As of the [1.11 update](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_1.11.0), this has changed. Now you need the [Cartography Table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cartography_Table), where you add one paper to the map to make it larger. If you want to make a new empty Locator map, you need a compass surrounded by 8 pieces of paper in a crafting table.